# Open path selector for file writing with PHP's fopen

Tags: php, forms, file, fopen, fwrite

The tile might be confusing but let me try to explain better:
I need to add a button (just like these used to open files) but with the intent of selecting a directory so I can pass it to an fopen and write the files I need in a PHP script.
Example code:

```
<form method="post" action="scripts/generate-parallax.php">
           <input type="path" name="path" placeholder="Select directory"></input>
           <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect blue darken-2">CONFIRM</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$path = fopen($_GET['path']);
```

Comment: Did I miss the creation of a `type="path"` HTML input type?

Comment: Try `<input type="text" name="path" placeholder="Select directory"></input>`

Comment: PS: **Its incredibly dangerous letting a user pick a path on your server!!!!!!!**

Comment: This is "pseudo" @RiggsFolly, there's no path. Text will be a text input, and it is on their computer, not my server.

Comment: You cannot write to a users PC from you server PHP code. You can send a file but the user will always get the option to put the file anywhere they like, or into the default sownload folder defined in THEIR browser